# Adding two text box values into SQL database table with WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have two textboxes and I want to store their values into an SQL database table.

however, I get the error for the command text

```
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

I dont know wether I am using the wrong syntax to combine the two values from the two textboxes or do I need another SQL statement for the second text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the problem lies with your command text. Try something like

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MemberInformation(Name, Age) VALUES(@nm, Age)";
```

You might also be better off doing the string concatenation before adding them to the database. Personally, I would replace the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text);` with

```
string val = string.Concat(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", val);
```

or maybe just

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm",string.Concat(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text));
```

if it works.